# How to fetch first record in transaction using scala?

Tags: mysql, scala, apache-spark-sql, hiveql, impala

My Data look like :

## [image]

I want to fetch first record of every dtcode with mini time of occurrences.

Desired Output :

[image]

By using scala i want to fetch.
Please guide me in building the logic.

Thanks,
Syam.

Comment: I agree with Jacques Amar below, the only way I see you can solve this problem is to manually loop over the whole dataframe yourself and check if the `dtcode` changed or not. It should be simply to do the program itself, however it will not be very efficient. If you could get a unique identifier for each group then `groupBy()` would be an easy alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought some more about your problem and came up with a better solution, using the `Window` functions of dataframes. First everything is ordered by `Currentdatedtime` and then each row is checked to see if `dtcode` has changed or not. Using your example data:

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
import spark.implicits._


val df = Seq(("7-1-2016 0:00:17",0),("7-1-2016 0:01:17",0),
    ("7-1-2016 0:02:17",4),("7-1-2016 0:03:17",4),
    ("7-1-2016 0:04:17",0),("7-1-2016 0:05:17",0),
    ("7-1-2016 0:06:17",0),("7-1-2016 0:07:17",5)).toDF("Currentdatedtime", "dtcode")

val w = Window.orderBy("Currentdatedtime")
val df2 = df.withColumn("dtcode_change",
   when(lag($"dtcode", 1).over(w) === $"dtcode", 0).
   otherwise(1))
 .filter($"dtcode_change" === 1)
 .drop("dtcode_change")
```

Will give you:

```
+----------------+------+
|Currentdatedtime|dtcode|
+----------------+------+
|7-1-2016 0:00:17|     0|
|7-1-2016 0:02:17|     4|
|7-1-2016 0:04:17|     0|
|7-1-2016 0:07:17|     5|
+----------------+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

--- EDITED with correct comment from Shaido ---

Usually, `GROUP BY` would handle this, if the order in the table is irrelevent,

SQL is good with grouping large amount of related data. However, your analysis is dependent on the order of data entry and the change is triggered by a change in one column which can be repeated later and can't be aggregated, while the other columns can continue changing.

In this case, you will need to LOOP over your data and detect the changes manually, as SQL doesn't have an easy way to group this kind of things. I answered a little too fast and had not noticed this.

This is best handled through a STORED PROCEDURE or a display language. I can give you the code in PHP if you'd like.

Another cheat will be to add a column that is used by GROUP BY (let's call it `groubycheat`) that is increased every time `dtcode` changes

```
SELECT MIN(Currentdatedtime) as Currentdatedtime, dtcode
FROM <tablename>
GROUP BY groupbycheat;
```

This STILL requires a LOOP to add the field, but if you need to get the results many times, then it's worth it. Otherwise ..no

Comment: groupBy won't work here as `dtcode` is not unique for each group. Check the example given again, there are two groups with 0.

Comment: Thanks for the reply shaido..


I want neither SQL or Scala 
I don't know the  PHP.
This data need to fetch from the HDFS.